# Execute Program Without Clicking

Tags: c#, c++, c

Is there a way for a program to be executed without clicking on it? Is it possible for it to be executed the minute you receive the file?

I want to build a c# application that executes any file sent to the machine from another machine connected to it. I want to do this without remote desktop, so I would check a checkbox that says "execute when finished sending" and when it is received, it would execute the program. So I would essentially be able to remote desktop, without actually remote desktoping.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From a security standpoint, I really hope that the answer to this question is *no*.

Comment: How are you 'sending' the file?  If you have a custom application running on the target machine that is responsible for receiving the file, you can presumably run the file with that.  Without it, no, that would be a prime candidate for a hacker, and so there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: +1 enlightening. Now I understand why 90% of the world's computers are infested with viruses.

Comment: @R, @e.James: Please note, he said "without clicking".  Not "without credentials".

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That's reasonable, but since Alex S did not mention credentials in this question, I am left to assume that they were not considered at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you realize what you are proposing? If this was possible, every machine out there would be infested with the nastiest viruses.

Why don't you build a server part that you leave running on your remote machine and then have it execute whatever your heart pleases.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program out there (currently in Beta) called SkyNet that does this. You can drag and drop a URL or file onto one of your "Contacts" and (for a URL) it will open an new tab and navigate to that site on your friend's computer. For files, it automatically drops them on that person's desktop.

So it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use [secure shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).  There are clients and servers for various platforms (you didn't specify) and you can run programs remotely.  This is useful for e.g. automated testing.